# How do i display the number of images on the "post screen"

Tags: plugins, images, count

I need help displaying the number of images in a POST on the post edit screen, For example if 5 images are attached to article A, and they are now reused on article C it should display the total number like the view count we have.

[image]

Comment: Hi @iamkingsleyf. Should the processing occur client-side or server-side? Could you please clarify your example that uses **article A** and **article C**? E.g. **post E** has no images. Five images are uploaded to **post F**. Then 3 of **post F**'s images are added to **post E**. I'm assuming **post E**'s image count is three. But, how would this change the image count for **post F**?

Comment: It should count any image on a post attached to that post or not.

Comment: Should the processing occur client-side or server-side? Is the code that renders the image count on the server (PHP) or in the client (JavaScript)?

Comment: Serber side, PHP (wordpress plugin) i do not have the code that is why I am here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below suggests one approach to handling the display of a post image count on the Post Edit List screen (edit.php). The function names provide an outline of what the code is doing. References to WordPress Documentation are below for details about the action and filter hooks used. Add the code to your plugin or child theme.

Images are counted with a simple regular expression matching the opening of an image tag (**<img**).

An **image_count** post meta data field is used to store the image count for a post. Using meta data allows for searching, filtering and sorting with WP Query.

The code assumes that images are counted for core WordPress Post types only. Different hooks are needed for custom post types.

```
/**
 * Register an image_count post meta key if you want
 * it to be available via WordPress REST API.
 */
function register_image_count_post_meta() {
    register_meta(
        'post',
        'image_count',
        array(
            'object_subtype'    => 'post',
            'description'       => 'Count of images in post.',
            'show_in_rest'      => true,
            'single'            => true,
            'type'              => 'integer',
            'default'           => 0,
            'sanitize_callback' => function( $value ) { return $value; }, // Replace with proper sanitization.
            'auth_callback'     => function() { return '__return_true'; } // Replace with proper authorization check.
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_image_count_post_meta', 10, 1 );


function add_post_screen_custom_headings( $columns ) {
    $columns['image_count'] = __( 'Images', 'translation_domain' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'add_post_screen_custom_headings', 10, 1 );


/**
 * Render content for the custom column.
 * A switch statement is commonly used when rendering several custom
 * columns.
 */
function add_post_screen_custom_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'image_count' :
            $single_value = true; // Single value. Not an array.

            $image_count = get_post_meta( $post_id , 'image_count', $single_value );
            echo $image_count;
            break;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_post_screen_custom_content', 10, 2 );


/**
 * This filter is needed to make the custom column
 * sortable on the post screen.
 */
function register_post_screen_images_column_as_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['image_count'] = 'image_count';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'register_post_screen_images_column_as_sortable' );


/**
 * If the user clicks the custom column header to sort the page
 * this function is called to update the WP Query.
 */
function update_post_screen_images_column_orderby( $query_vars ) {
    if ( isset( $query_vars['orderby'] ) && 'image_count' == $query_vars['orderby'] ) {
        $query_vars = array_merge( $query_vars, array(
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
            'meta_key'  => 'image_count',
            'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ) );
    }

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'update_post_screen_images_column_orderby' );


/**
 * This function is optional.
 * It suggests that you might want to initialize the image_count
 * meta data value for all posts that currently do not yet
 * have an image_count post meta key.
 */
function initialize_image_count() {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'image_count',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        )
    ) );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $count = preg_match_all( "/<img\s+/i", $post->post_content );

        if ( is_bool( $count ) ) {
            $image_count = 0;
        } else {
            $image_count = $count;
        }

        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_count', $image_count );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'initialize_image_count', 10, 1 );


/**
 * Whenever a post is updated, this function is called to update
 * the image_count.
 */
function dynamically_update_post_image_count( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $count = preg_match_all( "/<img\s+/i", $post->post_content );

    if ( is_bool( $count ) ) {
        $image_count = 0;
    } else {
        $image_count = $count;
    }

    if ( empty( $completion_date ) ) {
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'dynamically_update_post_image_count' );
        update_metadata( 'post', $post_id, 'image_count', $image_count );
        add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamically_update_post_image_count', 10, 3 );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamically_update_post_image_count', 10, 3 );
```

### Further Reading / Useful Links

[rest_api_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_api_init/)

- Fires when preparing to serve a REST API request.

[manage_posts_columns](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_posts_columns/)

- Filters the columns displayed in the Posts list table.

[manage_posts_custom_column](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_posts_custom_column/)

- Fires in each custom column in the Posts list table.

[manage_{$this->screen->id}_sortable_columns](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-id_sortable_columns/)

- Filters the list table sortable columns for a specific screen.

[request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/request/)

- Filters the array of parsed query variables.

[init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/)

- Fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent.

[save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/)

- Fires once a post has been saved.

[preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

- Counts regular expression matches in a string.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the code, it's working fine, and the sorting makes it wonderful. I have tested on one site.

Comment: Hi,

I want to add is it possible to also add the featured image as well? so it counts featured images too as part of the images on a post.

Comment: @iamkingsleyf Good question. Short answer is "yes". Long answer requires an update to my answer. Are you looking to learn how to do this yourself by making an effort at a solution? I can help. In any case, my answer should be updated to do at least two things: **1.** Move the calculation for `image_count` into its own function; and **2.** Change the regular expression used to calculate `image_count` to match strings like **class="wp-image-230"** instead of **<img**. The new regex can capture the image ID (which is *230* in this example), and be used to verify that an ID actually exists.

Comment: Alright thanks.